# how to connect oracle database and run query by powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can I connect to an Oracle database (11g)? I have a list of oracle servers and I want to execute a query on them from Jump Server (the Jump server has Powershell v2).

Servers are accessible from Jump Server as I am able to access them by UNC path.

**Update:**

I know it can be done by using ODP.Net connector. But i don't want to use it due to approval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the method using an `OleDbConnection` described [here](https://cmille19.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/querying-oracle-from-powershell-part-2/)

```
function Get-OLEDBData ($connectstring, $sql) {            
   $OLEDBConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connectstring)            
   $OLEDBConn.open()            
   $readcmd = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($sql,$OLEDBConn)            
   $readcmd.CommandTimeout = '300'            
   $da = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($readcmd)            
   $dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable            
   [void]$da.fill($dt)            
   $OLEDBConn.close()            
   return $dt            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try tomorrow. Voted up.

Comment: I checked the above code in my local machine. It seems like i need to install Get-OLEDBData. Do you know where can i get this?

Comment: The function `Get-OLEDBData` is the one described in the code block I pasted.

Comment: do i need to install anything? like ODP.net or something. Does it work if i want to run it on multiple server remotly.

Comment: I don't have an oracle server with which to test, but the blog I liked seems to indicate all you need is the actual Oracle Client Software installed. If you can't install ANY Oracle Libraries, I doubt you'll be able to access the DB directly at all.